# PowerShell: Working with Strings and Hashtables

Tags: string, powershell, hashtable

I have this code:

```
$passwordsParameters = "sysPassword = 12  &&& testPass = 13 &&& systemPassword = 10"

$parametersList = @($passwordsParameters -split '&&&')

$passwordsTable = @{}


ForEach ($parameter in $parametersList) {
    $splitToKeyValue = @($parameter -split '=')
    $passwordsTable += $passwordsTable = @{
        $splitToKeyValue[0].trim() = $splitToKeyValue[1].trim()
    }
}


ForEach ($pass in $passwordsTable.Keys) {
    if ($passwordsTable[$pass] -ne "") {
        Write-Host "set $pass ="$passwordsTable[$pass]"" 
    } else { 
        Write-Host "A value for the parameter $pass was not entered."
    }
}


# Add-Content "d:\myFile.txt" "set $pass ="$passwordsTable[$pass]""
```

Which perfectly works when I use Write-Host. But I want to do something like in the comment in line 25. I tried several ways but I always got a static string instead of the values that I get from the Hashtable.

At the end I want to have something like:

```
set pass1 = 12
set pass2 = 5
```

in myFile.txt

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change Write-Host (just prints to a console) to Write-Output ( which passes an object to a pipeline). Write-Output does not print to the console.

```
$passwordsParameters = "sysPassword = 12  &&& testPass = 13 &&& systemPassword = 10"
$parametersList = @($passwordsParameters -split '&&&')
$passwordsTable = @{}


ForEach ($parameter in $parametersList) {
    $splitToKeyValue = @($parameter -split '=')
    $passwordsTable += $passwordsTable = @{
        $splitToKeyValue[0].trim() = $splitToKeyValue[1].trim()
    }
}

$counter=0
ForEach ($pass in $passwordsTable.Keys) {
    if ($passwordsTable[$pass] -ne "") {
        $counter++
        Write-Output "set "pass$counter = $passwordsTable[$pass]"`n"  | Add-Content -NoNewline myFile.txt 
    } else { 
        Write-Host "A value for the parameter $pass was not entered."
    }
}
```

Output:

```
set pass1=10
set pass2=13
set pass3=12
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the first foreach loop if you simply replace all the `&&&` by a newline and use cmdlet `ConvertFrom-StringData`.

`Add-Content` also has a switch called `-PassThru` that will let you write to the file and also output to console.

```
$passwordsParameters = "sysPassword = 12  &&& testPass = 13 &&& systemPassword = 10"

$passwordsTable = $passwordsParameters -replace '&&&', [Environment]::NewLine | ConvertFrom-StringData

foreach ($pass in $passwordsTable.Keys) {
    if ($passwordsTable[$pass]) {
        $msg = 'set {0} = {1}' -f $pass, $passwordsTable[$pass]
        # or use: $msg = "set $pass = $($passwordsTable[$pass])" 

        # write this to the file. switch -PassThru will also output to the console
        Add-Content -Path 'D:\myFile.txt' -Value $msg -PassThru
    } else { 
        Write-Host "A value for the parameter '$pass' was not entered."
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Could you please explain this line to me: 
$msg = 'set {0} = {1}' -f $pass, $passwordsTable[$pass]

Thank you!